# FPGA implement look up table with LUTs

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I would like to implement a 8 to 1 multiplexer in FPGA. The inputs of the multiplexers are constants, so I use a look up table instead.

I know that fpgas are made of LUTs. Is there any hardware block that I can use in order to optimize the multiplexer?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to describe it as-is, and then had a look at what the synthesis tool generated? Normally you should not be concerned about this kind of optimisation until you see it leads to problems in synthesis

Comment: Usually you just implement what you need in VHDL/Verilog. The synthesis should be good enough to recognize your mux-problem. If you don't trust your program you can check which blocks the tool uses on the FPGA. The tool basically does two things. 1) Create out of your language logical circuits and 2) Putting it on your FPGA. (usually this consists out of 3 steps, using primitives, then maping then onto then FPGA and placing and routing them afterwards). You can evaluate the result in any of those stages.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, unless the each of the 8 "words" you're using is EXTREMELY large and could justify a blockRAM (discussion on when to use a blockRAM here - http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Virtex-Family-FPGAs/Lut-vs-Block-Ram/td-p/251888 ).   If your bus is only 1 bit, or 8 bits wide...just use a case statement.  The synthesis & routing stages will take care of converting that "code" into the individual LUTs on the FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, ISE is smart enough to infer a mux from your code.  You can verify this after running synthesis.  Check the Summary in the synthesis report.

If you really want to use LUTs as a good learning exercise, you certainly can do it using a few staged together.  Read [Understanding the INIT attribute for LUTs](http://www.markharvey.info/fpga/init/index.html) to learn how to use the INIT property.